# require_once with dotted (hidden) files in php on windows not working

Tags: php, windows

my code works fine if I remove the leading dots on file names, but breaks otherwise.

**[edit]**
The file starts with a dot (period) character
**[end edit]**

require_once('**.**htMyClass.inc.php'); //fails

require_once('htMyClass.inc.php'); //works

I wanted to keep the dots for security -- the leading **ht** is just a hold over from apache.  i don't expect that to do anything special on windows.

Comment: Are you saying the actual file has a leading dot?

Comment: Yes, the file starts with a dot (period) character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this Microsoft article, "[IIS Hidden Static Files Return HTTP 404 or Access Denied Errors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216803)," it could be failing on purpose. Extend that to not even being able to include the file.

Comment: Thanks Random Echo.  Looks like you're right.  
I suppose that means I need to look into securing files with NTFS permissions.  I'll start looking into best-practices for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I just run a test code, and worked fine.
I am using xammp in windows, it could be apache or php configuration in your machine.

```
<?php
require_once(".htphp.inc.php");
?>

<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

Comment: Should be a comment, as this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: it might not be the answer but proves that PHP can include/require any file no matter what the file name or extension is.

Comment: I'm not using XAMMP or Apache.  Including dotted files in Apache always worked for me.  Currently, I'm working with a manual install of (I think 5.2.8) php and IIS 5 on xp pro.  I haven't installed on windows server yet, but that will be IIS 6.

Comment: Are there php.ini settings that control access to hidden files?